# Change view controller on click UIButton Swift (without storyboard)

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uiviewcontroller, uibutton

How do you change the view controller when a button is clicked. I am not using the Storyboard. The views were  all created programmatically.

I tried adding a target to the button and then calling the following method to push the new View Controller:

```
func switchView() {
   print(123)
   let prodListController = ProductListController()
   self.navigationController?.pushViewController(prodListController, animated: true)
}
```

This was called from within the UIviewController class.

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!!

EDIT:
Made the following modifications:

```
window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
window?.rootViewController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: ProductListController())
```

Comment: If this code is not doing anything, then I think your `navigationController ` could be `nil`.

Answer (score 2):

Are you using navigationController? It looks like it is "nil"...

You can do it with "show" instead:

```
self.show(ProductListController(), sender: self)
```

However, if you want to use navigationController, you have to set it up first.
For example (supposing you will start your app with a navigationController):

on didFinishLaunchingWithOptions (AppDelegate.swift):

```
// Override point for customization after application launch.
self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)

let initialViewController = NavViewController()

self.window?.rootViewController = initialViewController
self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

return true
```

on viewDidLoad of NavViewController.swift:

```
self.pushViewController(ViewController(), animated: true)
```

and then, you can use your code for the button:

```
func switchView() {
    print(123)
    let prodListController = ProductListController()
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(prodListController, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: I have the code added to the AppDelagate. How would I add a view controller on top of it when I click a button?

Comment: You can use the code inside switchView() (see above) to show a new view controller. If you can't do it, tell me the name of the current view controller that is showing, and the view controller that you want to show.

Comment: I have that code exactly as the setupView but it doesn't show me the new view.

Comment: Do you have a NavViewController.swift for your navigation view controller? Also a ViewController.swift for your initial view controller? And a ProductListController.swift for your new view controller? Create a breakpoint on your button action method and check on the console "po self.navigationController?.viewControllers"

Comment: I do not have a NavViewController.swift

Comment: What is that exactly?

Comment: What exactly didn't you understand? What is a breakpoint? Do you know that arrow you put on your code so that the code stops running on that line?

Comment: I have a login page which leads to a productList page by making it the new root controller. I now want to go to the productDetail page when a button is clicked.

Comment: Ok,is the login page inside a navigation controller? Or are you starting the navigation controller after login?

Comment: I believe so. I did so in the AppDelagate.

Comment: If you don't want your login page to be inside a navigation view controller, you need to change your AppDelegate initialViewController to be the login page.  Then, after login succeeds you use the "show" (see above) to start the navigation controller, and inside navigation controller viewDidLoad you "push" the productList page

Comment: then, when the button inside productList page is clicked, "push" the productDetail page.

Comment: Did you find a solution?  If you have any more problems, please let me know  :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160671/discussion-between-diogo-souza-and-jundallah3).

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code to push another viewcontroller

```
self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
var navVC = UINavigationController()
var yourVC = YourViewController()
navVC.viewControllers = [yourVC]
self.window!.rootViewController = navVC
self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

hope this will resolve your problem.

Comment: I followed what you did but made some modification:

Comment: What would I do to add a view to the navigation controller? For example, when I click a button I want a new View Controller.

Comment: Use `self.navigationController?.viewControllers = [ViewController]` this to add ViewController.